# C++ sysmalloc: Assertion error after removing an output line

Tags: c++, c++20

I removed an output line (cout << "test" << endl;) in my code that I used for debugging, and after that the whole program would run into an error:

```
sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

and everything doesn't work. If I put back the line it would work again for some reason. I tried gdb but can't really find what happened. It says there's something to do with memory access but I don't see which part of my code causes the problem.

My Code is the following:

```
import <iostream>;
import <string>;
using namespace std;

struct Pixel {
    unsigned int r;  // value for red
    unsigned int g;  // value or green
    unsigned int b;  //value for blue
 
    static const unsigned int COLOUR_MAX=255;

  Pixel( unsigned int r = 0, unsigned int g = 0, unsigned int b = 0 ):
    r{r},g{g},b{b} {}
  
};

struct PpmArray {
  static const unsigned int INIT_SIZE = 5;

  int size;      // number of elements the array currently holds
  int capacity;  // number of elements the array could hold, given current
                       // memory allocation to pixels
  int width;     // width of image
  int height;    // height of image
  Pixel *pixels;

  PpmArray():
    size{0},capacity{1},width{0},
    height{0},pixels{new Pixel[1]}
  {}
  ~PpmArray(){
    delete [] pixels;
  }
  void add( Pixel p ){
    if(this->size==this->capacity){//double array if needed
      this->capacity *= 2;
      Pixel* tmp = this->pixels;
      this->pixels = new Pixel[this->capacity];
      //copy from old array
      for(int i=0;i<capacity/2;i++)(this->pixels)[i] = tmp[i];
      delete [] tmp;
    }
    this->pixels[this->size] = p;//add new pixel into array
    (this->size)++;
  }
  void flipHorizontal(){
    //make a temporary row holder
    Pixel* tmp_row = new Pixel[this->width];
    //loop each row
    for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
      //copy current row to tmprow
      for(int j=0;j<width;j++)tmp_row[j]=(this->pixels)[width*i + j];
      //reversly move tmprow contents back to original
      for(int j=0;j<width;j++) (this->pixels)[width*i + j] = tmp_row[width-j-1];
    }
    delete [] tmp_row;
  }
  void rotate(){
    Pixel* newpix = new Pixel[this->size];
    //store rotated array in temporary array
    for(int i=0;i<=this->height;i++){//i: old h, new w
      for(int j=0;j<=this->width;j++){//j: old w, new h
    newpix[i * (this->height) + j] = this->pixels[this->width * (this->height - j - 1) + i];
      }
    }
    //copy back and delete temp array
    for(int i=0;i<this->size;i++) this->pixels[i] = newpix[i];
    int w = this->height;
    this->height = this->width;
    this->width = w;
    delete [] newpix;
  }     
  void sepia(){
    for(int i=0;i<this->size;i++){
      Pixel p = (this->pixels)[i];
      Pixel np{ p.r *.393 + p.g * .769 + p.b * .189,
    p.r *.349 + p.g * .686 + p.b * .168,
    p.r *.272 + p.g * .534 + p.b * .131 };
      (this->pixels)[i] = np;
    }
  }
};

// Outputs the transformed PPM file to the specified output stream as a PPM file.
std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & out, const PpmArray & ppm ){
  out << "P3"<<endl;
  out << ppm.width <<" "<< ppm.height << endl;
  out << 255 << endl;
  int first = 1;
  int pix_count = 0;
  //loop over each element, then each row
  for(int i=0;i<ppm.height;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<ppm.width;j++){
      if(first != 1) out << " ";
      first = 0;
      out << (ppm.pixels[pix_count]).r << " ";
      out << (ppm.pixels[pix_count]).g << " ";
      out << (ppm.pixels[pix_count]).b;
      pix_count++;
    }
    first = 1;
    out << endl;
  }
  return out;
}

int main(){
  //PpmArray ppm;
  //cout << ppm.capacity << endl;
  // /*
  string red;
  string green;
  string blue;
  //create array
  PpmArray ppm;
   cout << "fffaa" <<endl;
  //fill the array
  while(true){
    cin >> red >> green >> blue;
    //if reaching end
    if(blue=="flip"||blue=="rotate"||blue=="sepia"||blue==""){
      ppm.width = stoi(red);
      ppm.height = stoi(green);
      if(blue=="flip") ppm.flipHorizontal();
      if(blue=="rotate") ppm.rotate();
      if(blue=="sepia")ppm.sepia();
      break;
    }
    else{//adding to array
      ppm.add(Pixel(stoi(red),stoi(green),stoi(blue)));
      
    }
  }//end of array filling loop
  //check if dimension matches size
  
  //loop for transformations
  string op="";
  for(cin>>op;!cin.fail();cin>>op){//assume at least one operation
    if(op=="flip") ppm.flipHorizontal();
    if(op=="rotate") ppm.rotate();
    if(op=="sepia")ppm.sepia();
    if((op!="")&&(op!="flip")
       &&(op!="rotate")&&(op!="sepia")){//case for error, random input
      cerr << "Error: Invalid input :: cerr";
      return 5;
    }
  }
  //print the final array
 
  cout << ppm;
  // */
}
```

Comment: You're corrupting memory somewhere, probably by going outside the bounds of an allocation. Run your program with AddressSanitizer and you should be able to narrow it down pretty easily. You might consider using a `std::vector` rather than a raw pointer so you can use `at(index)` to generate an exception when you access out of bounds. Things like `i<=this->height` are likely suspects. You almost always want to use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
fffaa`